# Nginx dynamic proxy_pass with variable location and relative url

Tags: nginx, proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, http-proxy

I used this Nginx configuration and **everything went well.**

```
server {
             listen       80;
             server_name  127.0.0.1;
             ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt;
             add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
             add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

             location ^~ /api/ {
                       rewrite /(.*) /proxy/$1;           
                    }

             location ^~ /js/ {
                       rewrite /(.*) /proxy/$1;
                    }

             location ^~ /services/ {
                       rewrite /(.*) /proxy/$1;
                    }

             location ^~ /payeewebv2/ {
                       rewrite /(.*) /proxy/$1;
                    }


             location /proxy/ {                      
                     proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT        $ssl_client_escaped_cert;
                     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
                     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;                    
                     proxy_pass https://proxieddomain.com/;
                     proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                     proxy_set_header host $proxy_host;

                 }
                }
```

Now I need to proxy to be determined by a COOKIE. I have updated the configuration and it looks like this:

```
server {
             listen       80;
             server_name  127.0.0.1;
             ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt;
             add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
             add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

             location ^~ /api/ {
                       rewrite /(.*) /proxy/$1;           
                    }

             location ^~ /js/ {
                       rewrite /(.*) /proxy/$1;
                    }

             location ^~ /services/ {
                       rewrite /(.*) /proxy/$1;
                    }

             location ^~ /payeewebv2/ {
                       rewrite /(.*) /proxy/$1;
                    }


             location /proxy/ {                      
                     resolver 127.0.0.11;
                     set $proxy "to_be_replaced";
                     proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT        $ssl_client_escaped_cert;
                     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
                     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                     set_by_lua_block $proxy {
                        return "https://proxieddomain.com/"
                      }
                     proxy_pass $proxy$request_uri;
                     proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                     proxy_set_header proxy $proxy$request_uri;
                     proxy_set_header host $proxy_host;

                 }
                }
           }
```

This is the changed part:

```
set_by_lua_block $proxy {
                            return "https://proxieddomain.com/"
                          }
proxy_pass $proxy$request_uri;
```

I can visit `http://localhost/varicent/` and it proxies to https://proxieddomain.com/

**But when its javascript requests `/api/something` etc. it returns content from** `$proxy` (https://proxieddomain.com/) and not from `$proxy/api/something` (https://proxieddomain.com/api/something).

Do you know why the first non-dynamic solution works without problems?
What should i change to make it work it like before?
Thx

Comment: `$request_uri` nginx variable doesn't get changed with the `rewrite` directive, it is an `$uri` one that does. Try to change `return "https://proxieddomain.com/"` to the `return "https://proxieddomain.com"` (remove the trailing slash) and `proxy_pass $proxy$request_uri;` to the `proxy_pass $proxy$uri$is_args$args;`.

Comment: I tried to change it and now I get 502 when visiting `https://localhost/payeewebv2/1` for example.

This is the nginx log:
`nginx_1  | 2021/11/02 20:59:04 [error] 13#13: *60 proxieddomain.com  could not be resolved (3: Host not found), client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /proxy/api/v1/customName HTTP/1.0", host: "localhost", referrer: "https://localhost/payeewebv2/1"`

Comment: Where did you get that `127.0.0.11` resolver IP address? Usually it is a docker-compose internal resolver used for resolving container names rather then real domain names had that IP address. Try any real DNS resolver like google `8.8.8.8` one (or use your own DNS).

Comment: No luck, both 8.8.8.8 and 127.0.0.11 resolves nothing.

Comment: Is your proxy domain name resolvable over the internet at all? Can you try `resolver 8.8.8.8 ipv6=off`?

Comment: I tried to add ipv6=off - no luck. The proxieddomain.com can be visited by browser and it worked for 100% in the first example.

Comment: I solved it by using canonical name from nslookup
and also by updating the config by your tips... thx

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been in really the domain.
I looked it up through nslookup and changed configuration to use *canonical name* which is different from the `https://proxieddommain.com`.
Thank you @IvanShatsky for your tip.